# Swagger gives me HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden

Tags: c#, asp.net, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swashbuckle

I am trying to use Swagger with Web API. I am just using the "Azure API App" template from the ASP.NET 4.6 templates installed with Visual Studio, which includes the `Swashbuckle.Core` and the `SwaggerConfig.cs`. The API works fine (I am able to call it successfully), but if I try to go to "http://mybaseurl/swagger/", I get this error:

> HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden The Web server is configured to not list
>   the contents of this directory.

It seems like Swagger is not getting loaded or something. Anyone else get this before? I can't seem to get around this. Thank you, and please let me know if I can provide more details.

Here is what my SwaggerConfig.cs looks like:

```
[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(SwaggerConfig), "Register")]

namespace With.Api
{
    public class SwaggerConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            var thisAssembly = typeof(SwaggerConfig).Assembly;

            config.EnableSwagger(c =>
            {
                c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "With.Api");
            })
            .EnableSwaggerUi();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try enabling `Directory Browsing` in IIS for this website.

Comment: No luck. That folder doesn't actually exist, the router should be routing me to the swagger-ui

Comment: Can you get the json dump by navigating to swagger/docs or swagger/{version}/docs?

Comment: I get a HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found. It's like swagger isn't even being loaded, even though if I debug it executes the code in the SwaggerConfig.cs

Comment: sounds like a routing issue. Just curious but have you tried runallmanagedmodules=true? - this happens to me ALL the time, when I create new templates and run them from a server.

Answer (score 17):

I just had the same problem. It worked fine when I deployed my app to Azure, but when I started it locally, Swagger just wouldn't show up just as described above.
Reverting to a previous version I knew was working before also didn't help, so it seemed to have something to do with IIS express. I'm not entirely sure what was causing the issue (I had changed some SSL related settings), but when I deleted the .vs folder (which contains the applicationhost.config file) and restarted Visual Studio, it started working again.

Comment: this worked for me. .net core app debuggin in VS 2019. suddenly stared getting 403. deleting the .vs folder fixed it.

Answer (score 13):

It's an old question, but it would be helpful for someone facing the same problem

If your project has a folder named `swagger` at root level, it conflicts and you will be not able to access swagger by `hostname/swagger`.

The solution is to just rename the Swagger folder to another name, then it works.

Comment: Thank you! I could not figure out what was happening. I created a directory to hold swagger customizations and could not figure out what had broken. There ought to be a warning of some kind about this in the doc.

Comment: yes, there should be some kind of warning or information

Comment: A curse on me for wanting to organize all Swagger related code into a folder appropriately named Swagger. How reckless am I? Very it turns out. Absolutely useless. Thank you for this solution to a problem that should have never existed in the first place

Answer (score 3):

Coming at you in 2021 / 2022, this is a fun one.

If you are on macOS, Apple's new airplay feature is on by default and listens to ports 5000 and 7000... sigh. Bad clash with the default swagger port (also 5000)!

Just go to System Preferences > Sharing > Uncheck "AirPlay Receiver" at the bottom of the list. Then restart your .NET application, and the Swagger UI should finally be showing up again in your browser!

Hoping this helps anyone who runs into this weird issue!

Comment: This is it. But the smarter way is to change your app to different port in launchSettings.json like `"applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5050"`

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue. After trying few things it still didn't work.
Then, I tried changing the Web API application port number as suggested at the link below and it worked. I'm not sure what caused the issue.

https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/618

Answer (score 1):

I have this issue and it's route and static directory conflict. 
For Web Api 2, make sure you don't have a static folder named 'swagger'.
For .NET Core, remove folder named 'swagger' in wwwroot.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this URL, `http://mybaseurl/swagger/ui/index` instead of `http://mybaseurl/swagger/`

Comment: Same result as before

Comment: Is Anonymous Authentication enabled for the website?

Comment: Yes, Anonymous Authentication is enabled for the website. Yes, the rest of the application is fine except for Swagger

Comment: I have been trying If I can reproduce this issue. But I couldn't. If something is not correct I was always getting 404 error and not 403. Can you paste your swaggerconfig in the question for me to take a look (you can remove comments in the config)?

Comment: Also, can you give full permission to the website folder for the user account you are using for your website? Honestly, just read-only is enough. But just to see if it is related to permission or not.

Comment: I added the contents of my SwaggerConfig.cs to my post. Yes, I have full permissions to the whole folder.

Comment: I think i am running out of ideas!!! can you access this path, `http://{yourbaseurlcontaining With.Api}/swagger/docs/v1`? An example, in my machine it was like `http://localhost/mytest.api/swagger/docs/v1` and it gives me a json in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

By some reason changing the order of calls in Application_Start, will fix the problem, this is what I have:

```
AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
**GlobalConfiguration.Configure(SwaggerConfig.Configure);**
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);  
XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

Answer (score 0):

This solved me in .net core web api

install this nuget package Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles

Answer (score 0):

I started my project and I added the NuGet for Swagger just "SwashBuckle" and swagger was working fine it I put my ...Localhost:1234/swagger it would redirect to /swagger/ui/index page.
Than I updated the NuGet packages and I added two classes in my code to create some filter for swagger. Than the error started..
When I put swagger on the url i get the 403 error.
I tried all the above and nothing worked, but what I realize is that I did something stupid where I put the two modules in a folder call "swagger" at the root of my project. As soon as I rename the folder to "swaggerExtraFilters" the redirect start to work again as normal.
I hope my stupid mistake help with your problem...